# NullPointerException while creating TextView dynamically inside custom ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, dynamically-generated, custom-adapter, android-inflate

I am having trouble creating a TextView dynamically inside my custom ArrayAdapter. I guess it has something to do with the inflated layout, but I can't find a similar case anywhere around.

I get NPE at this line:

```
likers[position] = new TextView(context);
```

I would be really thankful for a suggestion.

custom ArrayAdapter:

```
public class FeedGridViewAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<FeedItemsSetter> {
    private Context context;
    private int layoutResourceId;
    private ArrayList<FeedItemsSetter> data = new ArrayList<FeedItemsSetter>();
    private TextView locationName;
    private ImageView image;
    private ImageView feedUserImage;
    private TextView cityName;
    private TextView userInfo;
    private TextView[] likers;
    private String[] separatedDire;

    public FeedGridViewAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<FeedItemsSetter> data) {
        super(context, android.R.id.content, data); 
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater vi = (LayoutInflater) context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = vi.inflate(R.layout.feed_grid, null);

            FeedItemsSetter item = data.get(position);

            locationName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.locName);
            locationName.setText(item.getTitle());

            cityName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.cityName);
            cityName.setText(item.getCategory());

            userInfo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.feedUserName);
            userInfo.setText(item.getUser());

            feedUserImage = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.feedUserImage);
            Picasso.with(context)
            .load("https://graph.facebook.com/" + item.getUserId() + "/picture?type=large") 
            .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder)
            .error(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
            .transform(new RoundedTransformation(90, 4))
            .resize(100, 100)         
            .centerCrop()  
            .into(feedUserImage);  

            image = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.image);          
            Picasso.with(context).load("http://www.edmondvarga.com/gastrolove/uploads/" + item.getImage())
            .into(image); 

            separatedDire = item.getLiker().split(",");

            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.likerNames);

            likers[position] = new TextView(context); // <----- EXCEPTION AT THIS LINE

            likers[position].setText(separatedDire[0] + ", ");
            likers[position].setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#d52e2e"));
            likers[position].setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
            likers[position].setTextSize(13);                   

            layout.addView(likers[position]);

            likers[position].setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(View v) {                               
                    Intent in= new Intent(context, UserProfile.class);
                    in.putExtra("user", separatedDire[0]);
                    in.putExtra("userId", separatedDire[1]);
                    context.startActivity(in);                              
                }

            }); 



        return view;
    }
}
```

> 12-12 16:55:38.056: E/AndroidRuntime(28749): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   12-12 16:55:38.056: E/AndroidRuntime(28749): Process: com.fideli, PID:
>   28749 12-12 16:55:38.056: E/AndroidRuntime(28749):
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 12-12 16:55:38.056:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28749):  at
>   com.fideli.userimages.FeedGridViewAdapter.getView(FeedGridViewAdapter.java:78)
>   12-12 16:55:38.056: E/AndroidRuntime(28749):  at
>   com.fideli.userimages.OffersFragmentActivity.setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren(OffersFragmentActivity.java:368)
>   12-12 16:55:38.056: E/AndroidRuntime(28749):  at
>   com.fideli.userimages.OffersFragmentActivity.addToFeedGrid(OffersFragmentActivity.java:354)
>   12-12 16:55:38.056: E/AndroidRuntime(28749):  at
>   com.fideli.userimages.OffersFragmentActivity.getFeed(OffersFragmentActivity.java:343)
>   12-12 16:55:38.056: E/AndroidRuntime(28749):  at
>   com.fideli.userimages.OffersFragmentActivity$4.onSuccess(OffersFragmentActivity.java:172)
>   12-12 16:55:38.056: E/AndroidRuntime(28749):  at
>   com.loopj.android.http.JsonHttpResponseHandler$1$1.run(JsonHttpResponseHandler.java:126)
>   12-12 16:55:38.056: E/AndroidRuntime(28749):  at
>   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733) 12-12
>   16:55:38.056: E/AndroidRuntime(28749):    at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 12-12
>   16:55:38.056: E/AndroidRuntime(28749):    at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:146) 12-12 16:55:38.056:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28749):  at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5602) 12-12
>   16:55:38.056: E/AndroidRuntime(28749):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 12-12
>   16:55:38.056: E/AndroidRuntime(28749):    at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 12-12 16:55:38.056:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(28749):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1283)
>   12-12 16:55:38.056: E/AndroidRuntime(28749):  at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1099) 12-12
>   16:55:38.056: E/AndroidRuntime(28749):    at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: You've not initialized `likers`.

Comment: Where is your logcat?

Comment: @MikeM. how can I initialise a dynamically created view?

Comment: anyway ... this is a very bad idea ... first of all you are not reusing the convertView ... also if you scroll down and up your adapter will create new TextBox for the same position ... it would be better to store the values from those texboxes inside FeedItemsSetter model

Comment: isn't the problem also in setListViewHeightBasedOnChildren method?

Comment: @MarkoNiciforovic thanks, but thet is not a probl. :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not initialized likers array.You have to do something like:

```
      TextView[] likers = new TextView[4];
```

with the number of views You want to have inside the array.

Comment: instead `4` => `data.size()` fx in constructor but this whole code is a dead end, anyway

Comment: unfortunatelly not working, basically I have initialised the view before like: TextView likers[position] = new TextView(context); but I think it should be casted to View view. I guess

Comment: I know it is not really nice, but I need a OnClickListener on the names of the persons who like a picture.

Comment: then do not store those TextViews at all ... use setTag and put the user and userid(fx as some POJO class) inside it then in onClick use getTag with`View v`  ... also get rid of `separatedDire` it makes no sens becuase you are setting it every time getView is called